# Android- Scroll to selected item in nested recyclerviews

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, nestedrecyclerview

I have a Recyclerview inside another RecyclerView, the inner recyclerview item views are clickable. When I click any item view in the inner recyclerview, it is not scroll to top, I tried using scrollToPosition(position) and scrollTo(X, Y) methods but no luck. I guess I have to scroll the outter recyclerview to achieve it, but don't know how to scroll parent recyclerview from child recyclerview. Can somebody help me on this?

Regards,

Rajapandian.

Comment: Did you solve this?? If so can you please share the code asap?